# OpenJPA forward mapping tool order column specification during table creation

Tags: jpa-2.0, openjpa

We've set the following property in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

If I understand correctly, this is what tells the OpenJPA MappingTool that it should generate appropriate tables in database, should those **not** be found for corresponding managed entities.

What I have failed to figure out is whether there is any way to specify the *ordering* of columns which MappingTool persists once it gets hold of reference to EntityManager?

MappingDefaults doesn't provide for such a property (at least I couldn't find it) and practically the only way to do this is to re-implement a part of OpenJPA API in order to support this.

That option is currently not feasible for us and I would ask for any idea or guideline on how to specify column ordering - if any.

Our environment consists of the following stack:

- OpenJPA 2.0.1
- JDK 1.6.23
- Spring 3.0.5
- Maven 2.2.1
- IBM DB2 9.7 Express-C

I am also a bit surprised that there only a handful of such questions on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of columns for a particular table matter for your application, don't use SynchronizeMappings.

Comment: How would I then auto-generate the tables? Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, that the order of the columns isn't guaranteed, even if you execute the mapping tool for the same schema another time. 
I'm also working with IBM DB2 and here I have to be sure that the tables are created exactly the same in every instance. 
So I generated the DDL script once with the mapping tool and I'm only updating it if I do have changes in my data model.